# How to create a graph in C# using SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, graph

I'm using a `SQL Server` database and `C#` form, I want to create a `graph` in C# form with database data.

I use msdn sample codes but it didn't work; no error and no response!
Thank you for helping me ;)

```
// The Access database
string fileNameString = "data\\chartdata.mdb";

// Initialize a connection string   
string myConnectionString = "Data Source=" + fileNameString;

// Define the database query    
string mySelectQuery="SELECT Name, Sales FROM REPS ;";

// Create a database connection object using the connection string  
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);

// Create a database command on the connection using query  
SqlCommand myCommand = new sqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);

// Open the connection  
myCommand.Connection.Open();

// Create a database reader 
SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(myReader, "Name", myReader, "Sales");

// Close the reader and the connection
myReader.Close();
myConnection.Close();
```

Comment: You say **SQL Server** database, but the connection string really is for a **MS Access** database file... what now?? SQL Server or MS Access?? You definitely cannot use `SqlConnection` against an MS Access database file!

Comment: Sorry the name of database entered incorrectly ! It is Sqlserver database

Answer (score 0):

you can install and Use reporting services to create graph report and dashboard.

[MSDN link for SSRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239351.aspx)